# Exporting SQL results in Excel format

Tags: sql, sql-server

> exec master..xp_cmdshell'bcp "select * from [db name].[table name]"
>   queryout D:\testing1.xls -o "D:\querycommanddetails.txt" -T -c -C RAW'

I'm running above query on my local machine but System is showing output as 'NULL'.Can anybody help?

Comment: use `sqlcmd` instead.

Answer (score 1):

should be like this instead .. no `queryout` only `out`

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell'bcp "select * from [db name].[table name]" 
out "D:\testing1.xls" -o "D:\querycommanddetails.txt"  -e "D:\error.txt" -T -c -C RAW'
```

**EDIT:**

Try running this way from windows command prompt and see if it works

```
bcp "select * from [db name].[table name]" queryout "D:\testing1.xls" -c -T
```

Comment: just saying still not working is not enough .. what's the error you are getting?

Comment: same..SQL is showing NULL and nothing is exporting in Exxcel file

Comment: then check whether your table has any records or not?

Comment: it has..i have already check this..someone said remove -o option..but its also not working

Comment: use an error file and see what error you are getting exactly. see edit.

Comment: 'querycommanddeatils' text file is showing this error "An error occurred while processing the command line.
"

Comment: is there any solution?